# Modify bin labels histogram

Tags: r, histogram, axis-labels

I made the following histogram:

```
one <- c(2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,8)
hist(one, breaks = 3)
```

[image]

Instead of a range from 2-8 on the x-axis, I need three labels on the x-axis that summarize the range of values like this: 2-3; 4-5; 6-8

How can I modify the code for the x-axis to get just three labels, and in the correct location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to label midpoints for the ranges using:

```
h <- hist(one, breaks = 3, xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, h$mids, h$mids)
```

But if you want to have the labels be character strings naming the ranges, you have to do a little more work. Take a look at `str(h)` to see what you have to work with:

```
> str(h)
List of 6
 $ breaks  : num [1:4] 2 4 6 8
 $ counts  : int [1:3] 12 6 2
 $ density : num [1:3] 0.3 0.15 0.05
 $ mids    : num [1:3] 3 5 7
 $ xname   : chr "one"
 $ equidist: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

You can use the `breaks` element to construct axis labels:

```
h <- hist(one, breaks = 3, xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, h$mids, paste(h$breaks[1:3], h$breaks[2:4], sep=' - '))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand what is being specified in the square brackets within the paste command: paste(h$breaks[1:3], h$breaks[2:4], sep=' - '). Can you help me understand so I can generalize to other plots?

Comment: @windy You have three bars in your histogram (because you specified `breaks = 3`). As a result the `breaks` element of the response object from `hist` has 4 numbers (representing the cutpoints between the bars and the global minimum and maximum). The brackets in that expression are extracting the first three elements (the lower limit of each bar) and last three elements (the upper limit for each bar) to construct the ranges labels.